# How do I update values in a node console app in real time?

Tags: node.js, console

I have the following code:

```
let counter = 0;
function printProgress(){
    // process.stdout.write('\x1B[2J\x1B[0f');
    console.log("Count is: " + counter);
    counter++;
}

setInterval(function(){
  printProgress();
}, 1000)
```

Which produces output like this:

```
Count is: 0
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
etc...
```

Uncommenting...

```
process.stdout.write('\x1B[2J\x1B[0f');
```

...clears the screen and gives the *appearance* of updating the counter value (sort of what I want but not really). Instead of clearing the screen every time, how do I actually update/display the counter value in real time?

Comment: What do you actually mean by *"..in real time"*? Are you actually asking *"How to write to the same location on screen"*?

Comment: @NeilLunn yes thats what I mean

Answer (score 3):

Use [log-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-update)

```js
const logUpdate = require('log-update');

const frames = ['-', '\\', '|', '/'];
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    const frame = frames[i = ++i % frames.length];

    logUpdate(
`
        ♥♥
   ${frame} unicorns ${frame}
        ♥♥
`
    );
}, 80);
```

Answer (score 2):

here is try it

```
let counter = 0;
function printProgress() {
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
  process.stdout.write('Count is: ' + counter);
  counter++;
}

setInterval(function() {
  printProgress();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This does almost the same thing as all the text in the terminal blinks as if being erased and redrawn. Perhaps its not possible to do exactly what Im trying to do.

Comment: this the only method otherwise there no possible way to updateon terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jetty](https://github.com/fknsrs/jetty):

```
var Jetty = require("jetty");

var jetty = new Jetty(process.stdout);

jetty.clear();


let counter = 0;
function printProgress(){
  jetty.moveTo([0, 7]).text(counter.toString())
  counter++;
}

jetty.text("count: 0")
setInterval(function(){
  printProgress()
}, 1000)
```

Additionally, you can do many different things on your console using Jetty. It supports different colors, formatting and styles.